# Tkinter atualizar dados Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou tentado atualizar os dados assim que clicar no botao abrir aquivo. Mas nao atualiza. Fica com  valor que foi salvo na ultima vez que foi pressionado.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def Menu():
    #ABRIR ARQUIVO
    dest = open('caminho.csv', 'r')
    g = dest.read()


#MENU
    menu_inicial = Tk()
    menu_inicial.title('Ramah 1.0')
    larguraW = '500'
    alturaH = '250'
    menu_inicial.geometry('500x250+200+200')
    menu_inicial.resizable(False, False)
    menu_inicial.iconbitmap('th.ico')
    menu_inicial ['bg'] = 'blue'


    #TEXTO
    arq = Label(menu_inicial,
                text= 'Selecione a pasta de arquivo     ',
                bg= 'blue', font= 'Arial').grid(column=0)

    # BOTAO
    open_file = Button(menu_inicial, text='Abrir arquivo',
                       command=lambda: dire()).grid(column=1, row=0)

    # CAMINHO DA PASTA
    cam = StringVar(menu_inicial, value='{}'.format(g))
    cam0 = Entry(width= 50, bd=2, relief=SOLID, textvariable=cam).grid(column=0, row=1)
    cam1 = cam.get()

    #RADIO BUTTON ESPELHAR
    Espelhar = IntVar()
    esp = Label(menu_inicial,
               text= 'Selecione o espelhamento',
                    bg= 'blue', font= 'Arial').grid(column=0)
    X = Radiobutton(menu_inicial, text='Espelhar em X', variable= Espelhar,
                    bg= 'blue', font= 'Arial', value= 1).grid(column=0)
    Y = Radiobutton(menu_inicial, text='Espelhar em Y', variable= Espelhar,
                    bg= 'blue', font= 'Arial', value= 2).grid(column=0)

    #ROTACIONAR
    rot = Label(menu_inicial,
              text= 'Escrevar o valor a rotacionar',
              bg= 'blue', font= 'Arial').grid(column=1, row=1)

    rot = IntVar(menu_inicial)
    rot1 = Entry(width= 15, bd=2, relief=SOLID, textvariable=rot).grid(column=1, row=2)

    menu_inicial.mainloop()


def dire():
    destino = filedialog.askdirectory()
    with open('caminho.csv', 'w') as discsv:
        discsv.write(destino)



Menu()
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo dos dados que constam no ficheiro CSV?

Comment: é o caminho selecionado no: destino = filedialog.askdirectory(). Pq quero que fica salvo o ultimo caminho acessado

Answer (score -1):

Tens que atualizar a variável do caminho com a nova pasta selecionada.

```
cam.set(destino)
```